# Something in this CSS code is preventing my page from scrolling?

Tags: html, css

Sorry I'm very new to this so I'm probably being an idiot.

I'm in the process of building a website for my new startup and I've run into a problem, when using the below code it implements fine into my website but it completely stops me being able to scroll down the website, it may even be preventing the rest of the page loading for all I can tell. It does this to every page, all that loads is the top of every page but I can't seem to go anywhere, the scroll bar on the side disappears as well indicating there is no more content. If I delete the CSS everything goes back to normal.

Code as below (only works when it's a bit bigger but this is fine for my needs as it stands):

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #34495e;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 160px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
.content__container {
  font-weight: 600;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0 40px;
}
.content__container:before {
  content: '[';
  left: 0;
}
.content__container:after {
  content: ']';
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.content__container:after, .content__container:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: #16a085;
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 40px;
  -webkit-animation-name: opacity;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: opacity;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.content__container__text {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
.content__container__list {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 125px;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-animation-name: change;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 10s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: change;
  animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.content__container__list__item {
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes opacity {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes change {
  0%, 12.66%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  16.66%, 29.32% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -25%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -25%, 0);
  }
  33.32%,45.98% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  }
  49.98%,62.64% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -75%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -75%, 0);
  }
  66.64%,79.3% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  }
  83.3%,95.96% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -25%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -25%, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes opacity {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes change {
  0%, 12.66%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  16.66%, 29.32% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -25%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -25%, 0);
  }
  33.32%,45.98% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  }
  49.98%,62.64% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -75%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -75%, 0);
  }
  66.64%,79.3% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  }
  83.3%,95.96% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -25%, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, -25%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="content">
  <div class="content__container">
    <p class="content__container__text">
      We Are
    </p>
    
    <ul class="content__container__list">
      <li class="content__container__list__item">Freight Documents</li>
      <li class="content__container__list__item">Professional</li>
      <li class="content__container__list__item">Experienced</li>
      <li class="content__container__list__item">Reliable</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: usually that's from `overflow: hidden` or `position: fixed`

Comment: thanks, that was it!

Answer (score 4):

You've got `position: fixed` applied to your `body` which will stop the page from being scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you've given `position:fixed` to your body element.

Best is that you wrap your code in a div and then give that div this `position: fixed` styling as you're giving it to body.

But then you'll have to wrap other elements in a master div and give it a `margin-top` equal to the height of this code div.

Ideal is to not use the position fixed (if you don't want it to be sticking on top upon scroll) and instead simply give this div a fixed height.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: fixed;` from body , it remain the body in a fixed position. And add some content below, you can scroll.

Check out this for demo : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rRpmWK?editors=1100